# Problem with application build - custom JS implementation

Tags: orocommerce

I tried to add some custom JS logic and following the documentation (https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/javascript/js-quick-start/) tried o build the application after changes with "npm run build" but I got:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'parent' of 'this.themes[theme]' as it is undefined.
> [ERROR] Assets build for "admin.oro, blank, default, custom, my_theme" themes failed.
> Run the command php bin/console oro:assets:build --env=dev --verbose to see more information.

After the running command above i have only one warning in each theme:

> Module Warning (from ../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Deprecation This operation is parsed as:
> 10px - ($offset-x-s)
> but you may have intended it to mean:
> 10px (-($offset-x-s))

but i think it's not the case.

I tried with diffrent versions of node. What could be causing the problem? I'm running out of ideas...